# AX NumberSequence: Mark a number as used

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, number-sequence

How to mark a given number as used in a NumberSequence when this number was not generated by the number sequence?

Let's consider I imported the first 10 records of a custom table and the file already specified its ID from 01 to 10,
then i want to intercept insert() mark the given number as used so that after importing, the first manually created record will assign ID 11.

This would be something like updating the field 'Next' in the NumberSequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the [`NumberSequenceTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/numbersequencetable.aspx)`.NextRec` value to the desired value.
Make sure that format is correct.

Example code:

```
NumberSequenceTable numberSequenceTable;

ttsBegin;
select forUpdate numberSequenceTable
    where numberSequenceTable.NumberSequence == 'Acco_1' // as example
;
numberSequenceTable.NextRec = 11;
if (numberSequenceTable.validateField(fieldNum(NumberSequenceTable, NextRec))
    && numberSequenceTable.validateWrite()
)
{
    numberSequenceTable.update();
}
else
{
    throw error("Validation failed");
}
ttsCommit;
```